# The folder /var/lib/docker size increases and can not be reduced

Tags: docker

The folder /var/lib/docker size increases and can not be reduced

The folder /var/lib/docker size increases and can not reduce it, for that i tried to rotate the logs inside this folder by writing the following under each image inside docker-compose.yml file

```
......
logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-file: 5 
        max-size: 10m 
.....
```

however the above snippet of the code does not work? is there any way to rotate the logs of the docker

Comment: What's taking the space? What are you running? /var/lib/docker is a directory, there are more directories and files in there. Are you pulling lots of images, building lots of images, running images that modify the container filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

`/var/lib/docker` contains not only logs but also data for images, volumes, containers, networks etc.
To check which if these is using the space do

```
docker system df
```

This space can be reclaimed with `docker system prune --volumes` which will clean

```
  - all stopped containers
  - all networks not used by at least one container
  - all volumes not used by at least one container
  - all dangling images
  - all dangling build cache
```

And will not impact any running containers.